# Oracle need to remove decimal point

Tags: sql, oracle

Simple and quick question

If I have column have values in decimals

```
               number
                 10.20
                 13.4000
                 15.987
```

i Want to remove the decimal from display the output without decimal

```
                  number
                   1020
                   134000
                   15987
```

I have tried

```
                     select replace(number, '.','') from table
```

I got the result but is there any other way to solve it.

Comment: Are you sure? `13.4000` is exactly the same as `13.4` but result would be different.

Comment: the values must be of string type, then.

Comment: If that really is what you want to achieve - and it does seem a very odd requirement - then what is wrong with your current approach using `replace()`? Why are you looking for alternatives?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit well I jus need to replace the decimal value. as 1020.0 cant 10200 logically well removing a decimal is what i required.

Comment: @AlexPoole well i am trying to learn where i am getting wrong coz i found the requirement very odd so i thought some one has any other idea about it.

Comment: @JOHNPaul it's weird b/c you're drastically changing the value itself..why not store as a VARCHAR2 instead?

Comment: @JOHNPaul - what you are doing gives the result you expect, as you said in your question. If you think the requirement is odd too then you should be asking for clarification from whoever gave you this task. We don't have any more insight than you do. Maybe you're supposed to normalise all the values to the same number of decimal places (adding trailing zeros?) first, to preserve the meaning; I've seen that done putting say currency values in a fixed-format string before? But we can only guess...

Comment: *"simple and quick"* LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, values you're dealing with are strings, aren't they? Otherwise, you wouldn't have all those trailing zeros.

Anyway, if it happens that these are numbers after all, a little bit of mathematics might produce the desired result. For example:

```
SQL> with test (num) as
  2    (select 10.201  from dual union
  3     select 13.4000 from dual union
  4     select 15.987  from dual
  5    )
  6  select num,
  7  num * power(10, to_number(length(to_char(num - trunc(num))) - 1)) result
  8  from test;

       NUM     RESULT
---------- ----------
    10,201      10201
      13,4        134
    15,987      15987

SQL>
```